# Not able to connect to other machine in same network

Tags: windows-7, networking

I have two machines that run Windows 7 in the same network and same work group.
I turned off the firewall in both machine and I also mapped the IP address with computer name in a host file.

But I am not able to connect to the other machine from my system by computer name.
However, I am able to connect with IP address.

---

But from the other machine I am able to connect my machine by name and by IP address both.
So that means some thing is blocking in the other machine. How do I solve this?

Comment: What does "i of firewall" mean? Either way, sounds like a DNS issue.

Comment: agreed :) as u said it might be an dns issue :)@DaveRook

Comment: Both Win 7? What firewalls are you using?

And can't connect with what? Ping, RDP? hyperterminal?

Comment: What IP version you're using? What DNS server?

Comment: both Window 7 . ipV4 192.168.5.101

Comment: Same with RDP . i able to connect with IP . but not from name .

Answer (score 0):

Try runing ipconfig /flushdns in computer from which you are unable to connect the other computer by name.

Regards
David.

Comment: I did . But still same thing .